# Date validation with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression which checks the date if it is in the following formats (11-2-07, 1-25-2007, or 01/25/2007). My regular expression looks like this:

```
/^([\d{2}\d{1}])([\-\/])([\d{2}\d{1}])(\-\/)([\d{2}\d{4}])$/
```

when I enter dates in the dates in the  required format the method test() actually returns false. Can you please help me find the mistake ?

Comment: `[\d{2}\d{1}]` and `[\d{2}\d{4}]` only match a single character, did you mean to use `(a|b)` instead? Also, your first example of a valid date doesn't give enough information to know day-month ordering

Comment: Have you considered using moment.js?  There is an isValid() function.

Comment: The easy way: forget about using a regex and just use [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: If you want to build regex - use this to try them out https://regex101.com/ This way you can build your regex and test it as you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can select 1 or 2 digit occurrences with `\d{1,2}`.
2. There are missing square brackets in the last hypen / forward slash group.
3. And the last group should be `(\d{2}|\d{4})`.
4. No need to escape the forward slash inside the character classes.

   ```
   /^(\d{1,2})([\-/])(\d{1,2})([\-/])(\d{2}|\d{4})$/
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
var re = /^([0123]?[\d])([\-\/])([0123]?[\d])([\-\/])((19|20)?\d\d)$/;
```

1. First and third groups match day and month which can start only from `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`. If you know exact date format you can remove `3` from month group, or use `(0?[1-9]|1[012])` for month group and `(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` for day group.
2. Second and fourth groups match hyphen and slash separators.
3. And the last one group matches the year which starts from `19` or `20`.

```js
var re = /^([0123]?[\d])([\-\/])([0123]?[\d])([\-\/])((19|20)?\d\d)$/;

console.log('01-02-1999', re.test('01-02-1999'));
console.log('01/02/1999', re.test('01/02/1999'));
console.log('41-02-1999', re.test('41-02-1999'));
console.log('01/42/1999', re.test('01/42/1999'));
```